# Add more meta data to the sites' HTML

Tags: feature-request, data-analysis

I'm playing with [live filtering the Stack pages](https://stackapps.com/questions/4888/filter-se-questions-by-votes-views-and-rep) and am extracting information about views, reputation and votes from title or content of the page elements.

<kbd>[image: actual html, data only in title]</kbd>

As HTML title attributes and text content are always subject to changes, and also localization issues <sup><sup>[1]</sup></sup>, I'd like to request some raw `data-*` in the HTML:

```html
<div class="views supernova" title="1,114,180 views" data-views="1114180">
    1.1m views
</div>
```

<sup>*<sup>[1]</sup> I have to add `.replace( ' visitas', '' );` to that var `view` count for SOPT...*</sup>